# JAVA Http POST request in UTF-8

Tags: java, http, utf-8

My J2EE application is able to receive POST request from a JSP page, no problem about that.

But if I use another java application to send a POST request, the parameter received is not an UTF-8 string.

Here there is my code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/ITUNLPWebInterface/SimpleApi");
HttpURLConnection cox = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

cox.setDoInput(true);
cox.setDoOutput(true);
cox.setRequestMethod("POST");
cox.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
cox.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
cox.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(cox.getOutputStream());
String query = "tool=ner&input=şaşaşa";
dos.writeBytes(query);
dos.close();
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your reply

Comment: You try `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8` alter for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Same, the server cannot see the parameters...

Answer (score 14):

this work!!!.

```
package com.erenerdogan.utils;

import com.erenerdogan.webservice.ServiceInterface;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author erenerdogan
 */
public class WebService 
{
private String server;

    public WebService(String server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

private HttpPost createPostRequest(String method, Map<String, String> paramPairs){
    // Creating HTTP Post
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(server + "/" + method);
    // Building post parameters
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(paramPairs.size());
    for (String key : paramPairs.keySet()){
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, paramPairs.get(key)));
            System.out.println("Key : "+ key + " - Value : "+ paramPairs.get(key) );
    }

    // Url Encoding the POST parameters
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair,"UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return httpPost;
}

public String callServer(String method, Map<String, String> paramPairs) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

    // Creating HTTP client
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10 * 1000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 3 * 1000);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(createPostRequest(method, paramPairs));
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    String xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    return xml;
}
}
```

Comment: Tanks the most important line is` httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair,"UTF-8"));` It worked for me

Answer (score 6):

The docs for `DataOutputStream.writeBytes(String)` says

> Writes out the string to the underlying output stream as a sequence of bytes. Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, **by discarding its high eight bits**. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by the length of s.

Instead use `cox.getOutputStream().write(query.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

`DataOutputStream` is redundant here.

Comment: The method writeBytes(String) in the type DataOutputStream is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])
So I don't think we can use that way, no ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just did it, but still '?' instead of special character.

Comment: What encoding are you saving your source file in, and do you specify it to `javac`?

Comment: Ok, I found the bug, to make my request work with firefox (direct request), I had to receive in ISO-8859-1 and after convert into UTF-8. So now it's working but not anymore the firefox GET request form the URI address bar. At least...

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost port = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/ITUNLPWebInterface/SimpleApi");

List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tool", "ner"));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("input", "şaşaşa"));
//post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "ISO-8859-3")); //try this one

HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-3 seem to support your spechial character ş

Comment: Ok, I did, it's same, on the server I obtain, '?' instead of special character.

Comment: In my test case it works, can you post your result and your class that reads those params? so that iI can help you better

Comment: try other 2 things...
try to add ISO-8859-3 as charset
and try to edit post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "ISO-8859-3"));

Comment: I just tried it, and still '?', I will become crazy.
By the way, it's ISO-8859-9 because it's turkish, in my case.

Comment: pls put you server code, or some test case just to reproduce your behaviour

Answer (score 2):

It works form me:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
...
byte[] data = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
...
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
connection.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

a) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doesn't have a charset parameter; it's essentially limited to ASCII

b) to send non-ASCII characters, you need to encode them in UTF-8 (not the client's default encoding) *and* percent-escape them; see http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm for the details.

Answer (score 0):

base on HttpClient's Example "FluentRequests.java":

```
Content content = Request.Post("http://localhost:8080/ITUNLPWebInterface/SimpleApi")
        .body(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                Form.form()
                .add("tool", "ner")
                .add("input", "şaşaşa")
                .build(), "UTF-8"))
        .execute().returnContent();
System.out.println(content);
```