# Sending a POST request using HttpURLConnection - request body is a file that encodes UTF16 - JAVA

Tags: java, http, http-post, httpurlconnection, utf-16

I am trying to send an HTTP `POST` request, with `Content-Type` set to `application/json`, and a body that is a file encoded with UTF-16.

But, I get an error: `code = 400`

If I send the request via postman, it works (`code = 200`).

I guess I'm not adding the file properly.  How am I supposed to do this?

```
try {
    byte[] postData = readFile(new File(path));
    URL    url            = new URL( request );
    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput( true );
    conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json");
    try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
        wr.write(postData);
    }
    int i = conn.getResponseCode(); // i = 400;
} catch (IOException e) {}
return null;
```

Comment: what about adding charset?

Comment: i did that:
 conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-16"); 
It doesnt work ..

Comment: I would use postman, to test if the problem is at other end... Problem can comes from leading bytes. Some documents states that they are mandatory, and other that they are prohibited.

Comment: I used postman, it works there

Comment: `readFile` uses UTF-16 encoding to deal with input data? Maybe that is the problem... Maybe you need to read the `path` as UTF-16. Usually I was using stuff from apache to deal with http server as client. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823357/java-http-post-request-in-utf-8 - that way, when you write entity to post request, you can provide encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your file is saved in utf 16 encoding